# Circular Dependency detected error in PBI, how to fix it?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am running in to an error when I try to create some new columns.

This is the first one, which has worked very well:

[image]

I tried it this way, too:

[image]

And here is the second query (with the error included):

[image]

This makes no sense to me, and I am confused.

Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my data visual table: I am trying to add a column which calculates the average percentages per country for values which are not 'Site Status = Terminated'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular Dependency occurs in Calculated Columns due to row context transition. When using `CALCULATE`, behind the scenes it is adding every column as a filter for that row - this includes Calculated Columns. Therefore the second Calculated Column includes the first and vice-versa.

To better understand the Circular Dependency in Calculated Columns see these two excellent posts:
[Circular Dependency between Calculated Columns in a Table in DAX](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Blog/Circular-Dependency-between-Calculated-Columns-in-a-Table-in-DAX/ba-p/1877267)
[Understanding circular dependencies in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/)

**Possible solutions**

1. Use `ALLEXCEPT({Table}, {The column of interest})` or `REMOVEFILTERS({all other calculated columns})`. Example try:

```
CALCULATE(
  ...,
  ALLEXCEPT('All Sites TP1', [Site Status]),
  'All Sites TP1'[Site Status] <> "Terminated"
)
```

2. Use Measures instead of Calculated Columns in your case.

Comment: Thank you for this!! The articles are very informative; it's working now!

One more question: When I attempt to create a measure for my first column 'Performing Sites' It does not work the same as creating a column - any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: What is `'All Sites TP1'[No of Sites]`? Is it a Measure?

Comment: Yes, I have created a measure named No of Sites, which has the following DAX:

`No of Sites = COUNT('All Sites TP1'[Facility Country])`

This is simply counting the rows in the table 'All Sites TP1' and totalling these per Country.

Comment: It is recommended to use `COUNTROWS` over `COUNT`. `No of Sites = COUNTROWS('All Sites TP1')`. How different is the measure vs calculated column in terms of the values?

Comment: Perfect, works well now as a measure, thank you once again :)